# Ruby Check condition if a string include multi-different strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie to Ruby. Are there any better ways to write this:

```
if (mystring.include? "string1") || (mystring.include? "string2") ||
   (mystring.include? "string3")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, as below :

```
if %w(string1 string2 string3).any? { |s| my_string.include? s }
  # your code
end
```

Here is the documentation : [`Enumerable#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns `true` if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil. If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of `{ |obj| obj }` that will cause any? to return true if at least one of the collection members is not `false` or `nil`.

Here is another way ( more fastest) :

```
[13] pry(main)> ary = %w(string1 string2 string3)
=> ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
[14] pry(main)> Regexp.union(ary)
=> /string1|string2|string3/
[15] pry(main)> "abbcstring2"[Regexp.union(ary)]
=> "string2"
[16] pry(main)> "abbcstring"[Regexp.union(ary)]
=> nil
```

Just read [`Regexp::union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) and [`str[regexp] → new_str or nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) .

Comment: Wow! very prettier and precise :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could always use a regular expression here (risking another jwz quote :)

```
if mystring =~ /string1|string2|string3/
  ...
end
```